# Google API authentication: blocked origin for the client

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

There is a login process by google on the login page of my website.
There are a lot of web app credentials in the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs in the google console.
The defined oauth2 credentials are working except one. When I use these defected credentials then it returns a blocked response
I've added Origin and redirected Url in the google console.
I have no idea what **blocked** means and what should i do.

**Request URL**

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=checkOrigin&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.website.com&client_id=3**-v*.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

**Payload**

```
{
  action: checkOrigin,
  origin: https://app.website.com,
  client_id: 3**-v*.apps.googleusercontent.com
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  blocked: true,
  suppressed: false,
  valid: true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) google say:

> *We are discontinuing the Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web. The library will be unavailable for download after the March
> 31, 2023 deprecation date. Instead, use the new Google Identity
> Services for Web. By default, newly created Client IDs are now blocked
> from using the older Platform Library, existing Client IDs are
> unaffected. New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can set
> `plugin_name` to enable use of the Google Platform Library.*