# Google Earth Engine Client Javascript API authentication is not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-earth-engine

I have read the `Google Earth Engine` Client side `Javascript API` documentation. Here is the minimal code to start using Google Earth Engine [Google Earth Engine Try it yourself](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/custom-apps/client-js#try_it_yourself)

I have signed up for the Google Earth Engine [here](https://signup.earthengine.google.com/#!/) using my Google Account.

I have also followed all the [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/custom-apps/client-js#prerequisites) step for `creating Project`, `Enabling Google Earth Engin API`, `Creating oAuth Client ID` and Setting up everything.

The issue that I am facing here is that the code is not working as expected, when I went to the console and saw network tab, I realized there is a request of checkOrigin which always return

```
{
  blocked:true
  suppressed:false    
  valid:true
}
```

Same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283092/google-accounts-return-blocked-true-on-integration) question. While I have added the origin in `Authorised JavaScript origins` while creating `API` for `Web Application`.

[image: Javascript Origin Added To API]

`NOTE: I am using wampserver and I have also added tested emails to the project.`

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myworkingGoolgeMapKey&callback=doNothing"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/earthengine/0.1.336/earthengine-api.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map. */
      #map-container {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The "Sign in with Google" button, initially hidden. -->
    <input
      id="g-sign-in"
      type="image"
      src="https://developers.google.com/identity/images/btn_google_signin_light_normal_web.png"
      onclick="onSignInButtonClick()"
      alt="Sign in with Google"
      hidden
    />

    <!-- Element where map will be added. -->
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script>
      function doNothing(){
        console.log("ok");
      }

      function errorInit(){
        console.log("initialize error");
      }

      // The OAuth Client ID from the Google Developers Console.
      const CLIENT_ID = "myclientidFromoAuth.apps.googleusercontent.com";
      
      // Initializes Maps JavaScript API and Earth Engine API, instructing the map
      // to pull tiles from Earth Engine and to overlay them on the map.
      function setUpMap() {
        // Hide the sign-in button.
        document.getElementById("g-sign-in").setAttribute("hidden", "true");
      
        // Initialize the Earth Engine API. Must be called once before using the API.
        ee.initialize();
      
        // Get a reference to the placeholder DOM element to contain the map.
        const mapContainerEl = document.getElementById("map-container");
      
        // Create an interactive map inside the placeholder DOM element.
        const embeddedMap = new google.maps.Map(mapContainerEl, {
          // Pan and zoom initial map viewport to Grand Canyon.
          center: {lng: -112.8598, lat: 36.2841},
          zoom: 9,
        });
      
        // Obtain reference to digital elevation model and apply algorithm to
        // calculate slope.
        const srtm = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4");
        const slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);
      
        // Create a new tile source to fetch visible tiles on demand and display them
        // on the map.
        const mapId = slope.getMap({min: 0, max: 60});
        const tileSource = new ee.layers.EarthEngineTileSource(mapId);
        const overlay = new ee.layers.ImageOverlay(tileSource);
        embeddedMap.overlayMapTypes.push(overlay);
      }
      
      // Handles clicks on the sign-in button.
      function onSignInButtonClick() {
        // Display popup allowing the user to sign in with their Google account and to
        // grant appropriate permissions to the app.
        ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(setUpMap);
      }
      
      // If the user is signed in, display a popup requesting permissions needed to
     
      
      // If the user is signed in, display a popup requesting permissions needed to
      // run the app, otherwise show the sign-in button.
      $(document).ready(function(){
        ee.data.authenticateViaOauth(
          // The OAuth Client ID defined above.
          CLIENT_ID,
          // Callback invoked immediately when user is already signed in.
          setUpMap,
          // Show authentication errors in a popup.
          errorInit,
          // Request permission to only read and compute Earth Engine data on behalf of
          // user.
          /* extraScopes = */ ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine'],
          // Show sign-in button if reusing existing credentials fails.
          () => document.getElementById("g-sign-in").removeAttribute("hidden"),
          // Don't require ability to write and access Cloud Platform on behalf of the
          // user.
          /* opt_suppressDefaultScopes = */ true
        );
      });
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: @Bwyss I didn't get any progress as I did not get any answer here. I tried other ways too but was not successfull. Let me know if you get any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

basically the issue is caused by the recent deprecation of google auth library (similar issue: [Google API authentication: blocked origin for the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72609813/google-api-authentication-blocked-origin-for-the-client)). To solve this issue, you could either wait for the lib maintainer to migrate the auth library to the newer one, or migrate it by yourself

I guess you could also raise this issue to this google group https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers, so that the maintainer aware of this

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have raised the issue to google group. You're right.